# How to setup ffmpeg in docker container

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I want to compress the video from project directory using ffmpeg in python

the video is saved from `cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)`

Normally it run without problem in my local machine, but when I dockerize my app it seems docker container can't recognize ffmpeg or I missed something.

```
def compress(name):
    with open(name) as f:
        output = name[0:-4] + "-f"+ ".mp4"
        input = name
        subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i ' + input + ' -vcodec libx264 ' + output)

video = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url) # This is where the video comming from
fileName = saveToProjDir(video) # Save the video to project directory and return the name
compress(fileName) # Compress the video
```

It throws exception

```
Exception in thread Thread-8 (compress):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/app/main.py", line 59, in compress
    subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i ' + input + ' -vcodec libx264 ' + output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 546, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1899, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -i cam1_2022-11-15125845.avi -vcodec libx264 cam1_2022-11-15125845-f.mp4'
```

This is how I docker my python app.

```
FROM python:3.11.0

WORKDIR /app/

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV = /env
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

ADD main.py .
CMD ["python","/app/main.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug your problem my suggestion is to use your container interactively.

Try running a new container like this:

```
docker run -t -i <image-name-or-container-id> /bin/bash
```

Or attach to your running container:

```
docker exec -i -t <container-id> /bin/bash
```

In this way you can play around, try to launch ffmpeg from different paths, install other dependencies and finally see what you are missing.

Comment: thankyou.. now i saw some progress .. this is the step i do 
`docker run -t -i imagename /bin/bash`

`python main.py` still it throws exception

`ls -l` to check all files in directory
i saw the videofile is saved but not compressed cause it throws exception

but when i manually run the command `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 output.mp4` in root terminal like i do in `subprocess.run()` it WORKED..

now i think the ffmpeg is installed correctly on my container.. do you have any idea why it throws exception in subprocess.run() but not on root terminal?

Comment: a possible issue could be not using the shell, you can try changing the command to `subprocess.run(..., shell=True)`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: O my god it workedd! thankyou verrymuch..

Answer (score 1):

If the python script mentioned in the beginning of the question is the content of `main.py`, then there are few issues with the implementation:

- You cannot run docker with the `python:3.11.0` as base image.
- You need to mount the volume with the videos and just process them inside the container.

Comment: Sorry, the video is coming from rtsp url using OpenCV and save it on to my project root directory.

Then I compress it using ffmpeg.

What i think is it seems docker container don't recognize ffmpeg dependencies / library

I will update my main question to make it clearer
```
video = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp url")
fileName = saveToProjDir(video)
compress(fileName) # This is where i call subrprocess.run() to compress the video using ffmpeg

```

Comment: Ok. In that case the second point does not apply. But the first point of running docker within the docker still applies. (I'm referring to this line: `subprocess.run('docker run ffmpeg -i ' + name + ' -vcodec libx264 ' + output)`)

You can check if the video is saved in the project's root directory by connecting to the docker either by `docker run -it ...` or `docker exec ...`. Also check if you are pointing to the right directory in the code to fetch the video. Better option is to have a `WORKDIR` specified in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thankyou now i got some progress .. this the step i do .. i add workdir on docker file and update the subprocess.run() as you can see above and still no luck.  But still i got some progress.

Comment: i do `docker run -t -i imagename /bin/bash` and  `python main.py` still it throws exception... `ls -l` to check all files in directory i saw the videofile is saved but not compressed cause it throws exception but when i manually run the command `ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 output.mp4` in root terminal like i do in `subprocess.run()` it WORKED.. now i think the ffmpeg is installed correctly on my container.. do you have any idea why it throws exception in subprocess.run() but not on root terminal?

Comment: @TorR did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I just add shell = True
-  `subprocess.run(...,)`
+ `subprocess.run(..., shell=True)`